# Eclipse m2eclipse can't find any mysql in dependencies search

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, m2eclipse

I am learning Maven and trying to find it's often told ability to download required jars automatically. Now I need to access Mysql database in my application. So I opened `Dependencies` tab in `pom.xml` visual editor and selected `Add...` button. Then I entered `mysql` in the search string.

Eclipse found nothing.

It this true that Mysql JDBC libraries are not on the Maven (central?) repository? Or may be I just configured something incorrectly? Can Maven show itself in the task of looking for JDBC library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql is in the central Maven repo. M2E uses this repo. You can see all active repositories in Eclipse's Maven repository view (`Window > Show View > Other... > Maven > Maven Repositories`). In the context menu of an repository you can update or repair the repository's index.

Comment: I have "central" repository there `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`, but still can't add mysql by finding.

Comment: Is it in the repository's index when you look for it manually? I.e. navigate in the folder structure in the Maven repository view to `Global Repositories > Central > mysql > mysql-connector-java`.

Comment: How to look index manually? When I open `central` in `Maven Repositories` window, I see no subnodes.

Comment: I did `Rebuild Index` and it helped!

Comment: Enable the full index in the context menu, then you can update it - and then it should be available. Btw, you are using the embedded version of Maven or an external?

Comment: Initially I was using embedded, but in the process I have switched to external.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mysqlconnector is in the maven repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

You can additionaly check it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18).

> It this true that Mysql JDBC libraries are not on the Maven (central?) repository?

MySQL JDBC connector is on maven repository.

> Or may be I just configured something incorrectly?

I have not used eclipse with maven but you might want to verify that maven looks up repositories you want (check `settings.xml` and check maven build logs).

Comment: May be my `m2eclipse` just configured with another repository then?

Comment: @SuzanCioc, unfortunately I cannot help you with `m2eclipse`. I think that `m2eclipse` uses global maven settings which should be located at `M2_HOME\settings.xml`.

Comment: Eclipse says that User Setting are placed in `<home>/.m2/settings.xml`, but this file is absent. Is there some other global `settings.xml` somewhere else?

Comment: @SuzanCioc, you may define other `settings.xml`s but I dont think that this is your case. The location of this file differs from one operating system to another. You could try to use operating system's search functionality to find it.